# KnockoutJS value not auto calculating

Tags: knockout.js

I have the following code:

**View:**

```
<table>
    <thead><tr>
        <th>Food</th><th>Quantity</th><th>Price</th><th>Total</th>
    </tr></thead>
    <tbody data-bind="foreach: lines">
    <tr>
        <td><input data-bind="value: name()" /></td>
        <td><input data-bind="value: quantity()"></td>        
        <td><input data-bind="value: price()"></td>
        <td data-bind="text: total()"></td>       
    </tr>    
</tbody>
</table>
```

**Viewmodel:**

```
function line(name, quantity, price) {
    var self = this;
    self.name = ko.observable(name);
    self.quantity= ko.observable(quantity);
    self.price = ko.observable(price);
    self.total = ko.computed(function(){
        var x = (self.quantity() * self.price());
        return x;
    }, self);
}

function MyViewModel() {
    var self = this;
    self.lines = ko.observableArray([
        new line("Steve", 2, 7),
        new line("Bert", 5, 9)
    ]);
};

ko.applyBindings(new MyViewModel());
```

When I run it I get the correct initial printout, but when I change quantity or price on any line item, the total does not change, what am I missing here?

Comment: Does the value change after you leave the input field?

Comment: No it does not unfortunately

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your computed value would update properly, but you have bound your UI elements to the original values of the observables instead of the actual observables. Remove the parentheses and it should work.

e.g. Replace `data-bind="text: total()"` with `data-bind="text: total"`